# Get request method in Silex middleware

Tags: httprequest, silex

Is it possible to get the request method (GET, POST, PUT, ...) in a middleware function ?

```
$myMiddleware = function (Request $request) {
    // This is what I want to achieve
    switch ($request->request->get('method') { 
        case 'GET':
            // ...
        break;
    }
}

$app = new Application();
$app->before($myMiddleware);
```

Comment: Is it not just `$request->getMethod()` or `$request->get('method');`?

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to putvande.
As simple as:

```
$request->getMethod();
```